# select linq retorna null

Tags: c#, linq

Estoy leyendo un archivo csv y colocandolo en ésta estructura:

```
List<Dictionary<string, object>> l = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
```

El codigo que tengo para realizar esto es:

```
        string path = "test.csv";
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> l = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            var header = reader.ReadLine();
            var keys = header.Split(";");

            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                var values = line.Split(';');

                for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    Dictionary<string, object> d = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    d.Add(keys[i], values[i]);
                    l.Add(d);
                }
            }
        }
```

Para recorrer la estructura uso lo siguiente:

```
            foreach (var item in l)
            {
                foreach (var dic in item)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(dic.Key + " " + dic.Value);
                }
            }
```

Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es un select de los valores del diccionario por clave, pero no me funciona, al hacer:

```
var v = l.Select(a => a["cod_curso"]);
```

Obtengo null.

**"cod_curso"** es una columna del archivo csv y esta como clave en el diccionario

Y la siguiente imagen es lo que obtengo en el debug

[image: Debug]

**Como podría lograr lo que estoy buscando? O por qué sucede esto?**

Answer (score 0):

Cuando usas diccionarios solo tienes dos columnas (por decirlo de una forma) key y value. No importa si desde tu archivo de llamaba "cod_curso" u de otra forma. El linq que necesitas es:

```
var v = l.Select(a => a.Keys);
```